# Will Parallels be safe while upgrading to El Capitan?

Tags: time-machine, backup, software-update, parallels-desktop

The new update seems pretty legit, so I am considering updating my macbook.

I have Parallels installed on my computer, and I don't want it to be removed or damaged during the installation of El Capitan.

If I use time machine to back up my macbook, will it back up everything and keep Parallels and the files on it safe? Or, will it only store original Mac files, ignoring parallels?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't set Time Machine to exclude any files from the backup, you should be fine.

If you want to be really cautious, you can find the Parallels virtual machine file and manually copy it onto your external hard drive, free space permitting. Put it at the top level of the drive, not in the Backups.backupdb folder.

This will keep your files safe on your external hard drive no matter what happens on your computer. To make sure you can keep actually using Parallels, though, you'll need to make sure you're on Parallels version 10 or 11. Version 9 **will not be supported** in El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

Parallels has said that "Parallels Desktop 10 for Mac will run on OS X El Capitan (10.11) as long as you are on the latest update" and directs customers to this KB to ensure you are up to date on v10:

- http://kb.parallels.com/111603

They recommend upgrading to Parallels 11 which *is* optimized for El Capitan. Some things that are broken in 10 are:

> You will NOT be able to drag and drop files from Windows to Mac or use Windows Applications in full screen

So, you won't lose any files and you'll just want to be sure you're up to date with 10 according to that KB before making the jump.

Answer (score -2):

I know I'm not directly answering your question: on my Book Air i7 8gb ram, after upgrading to El Capitain, my Windows setup (Win XP and Win 10) are running extremely slow from an external usb 3.0 SSD.

Before upgrading all was running much quicker!

My Parallels version is last one.

Answer (score -2):

- Slow on 10.11. After upgrading from Yosmite to OS X El Capitan
  (10.11), Paralles Desktop 11327 runs extremely slow from an external
  usb3.0 drive.
- Fast on Yosmite. On Yosmite, Paralles Desktop 11327 runs fast from
  the same external usb 3.0.
- But, fast on local drive. OS X El Capitan, Paralles Desktop 11327
  runs fast on the local drive.

Answer (score -2):

Parallels is running and starting extremely slow. Almost unusable really. Running the latest build of Parallels Desktop 10. I don't know if upgrading to Parallels 11 will fix it....almost afraid to.